# How to compute an encryption key using KDF by using AES based CMAC as PRF in .net framework 4.7.1?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cmac, kdf

I am trying to create an encryption key from a known master key using a key derivation function. The NIST Publication 800-108 contains recommendation for key derivation using pseudorandom functions (PRF). This document has several KDF modes defined in it. I am trying to use KDF in Counter Mode (as outlined in section 5.1). This (as other KDF modes in this spec) use PRF, which according to section 4 can be HMAC or CMAC.

I have all the inputs K, Label. Context and L that can be go into KDF in Counter Mode.
I would like to use AES based CMAC as PRF.

How can I compute the following step (i.e. PRF(s, x)) in KDF in Counter Mode using AES based CMAC?

K(i) := PRF (KI, [i]2 || Label || 0x00 || Context || [L]2) which is basically PRF(s, x)

The only reference remotely related to MAC that I found is System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES.

Comment: Use PBKDF2, with a random salt and a round count such that it consumes ~100ms of CPU time.

Comment: .NET doesn't provide CMAC, but you can write it. http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38b.pdf.  (HMAC, on the other hand, is provided)